# Generation and propagation of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

How EM waves are generated?
How do EM waves travel in space?
like in many text books they have given an electric field sine wave perpendicular to magnetic field sine wave....is it exactly like that???
Varying magnetic field creates a varying electric field and this electric field creates another magnetic field and so on...is it correct? Does the EM wave propagate like this?
Correct me if I'm wrong....

Comment: You are not wrong, but you haven't done your homework, either.

Comment: Investigate the time dependent Maxwell equations. Changing E-fields are related to B- fields. Changing B-fields are related to E-fields.